# One join table for two Many-to-Many relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, join

I'm working on a solution for adding tags to two differente entities.
in order to get data easily in the frontend i created a joinTable named Tag_Mapping like this :

```
class TagMapping
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $tag;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Feed", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $feed;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $question;
...
}
```

The Tag Entity :

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TagMapping", mappedBy="tag", cascade="remove")
     */
    private $tags;

    ...
}
```

and in both other entities (Feed and Question) I made reference to TagMapping entity like this

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @JoinTable(name="tag_mapping",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="feed_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */

 private $tags;  
...
```

the problem I'm facing is that it's not a valid way to do it, as it shows an error when i'm trying to execute :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

saying that tag_mapping table already exists.
do you have any idea how can i get it done using only one joinTable instead of one for each relation ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure about your relational model ? it seems to me that there is a redundancy in it.

Comment: that's the problem, normaly the relations should be like this :

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TagMaping", mappedBy="feed", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $tags;

but when i do so, i have no idea how to manage them using sonata-admin-bundle